# Is it possible to remotely determine mapped drives of a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, mapped-drive

If needing to access the shares of a remote machine, it's possible to type the hostname of the machine in question - and if necessary, follow it with the name of one of its mapped drives - like so:

\Hostname-of-Machine\D$

If the connecting machine has the permissions to do so, the above command will allow the browsing of the drive mapped as the letter "D" on the remote machine. Taking this into account, is there an easy way to find out all drive mappings on the remote machine - rather than just simply guessing at letters?

Comment: Semantics, but a shared drive is not a mapped drive.  A mapped drive is when you create a local drive letter using a remote share, not the other way around.  "Find out all drive mappings".. no, "find out all published shares"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can start **mmc.exe** -> File -> Add or Remove snap-ins -> Shared folders -> "Another computer" -> then, look at the "Shares"